# Safe to use asyncio in Django?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, python-asyncio

I have a small Django app that is highly dependent on other services. In one situation, the client makes one request to our app, and the Django app makes 3 or 4 requests to another server, aggregates the data, and saves it. This is a slow process as I need to make these calls synchronously although there is no requirement for the requests to be made sequentially.

Given the above, this particular set of calls seem like a good candidate for async programming and the asyncio package is provided with newer Python versions.

I’ve implemented what I have described using loop.run_until_complete and hooked it into a view and it seems to work fine, as well as provide a significant performance increase.

However, I am worried that I am missing something in the magic. Doing multiple google searches on whether this is a good idea in Django has given me a mixed bag of answers and I’m still unclear on the negatives of doing so.

I realize this could all be done by JavaScript client in a well supported manner, I’m just trying to reduce complexity on that side, and am more interested in the implications of doing this running Django in prod environment with WSGI.

Comment: I've used this approach in one of my projects a couple of years ago and it's been running in production ever since without problems. I've been googling a lot at that time, same as you, and eventually decided that this is a completely valid use case.

Comment: I see no problem whatsoever in using `run_until_complete` in this manner. That's why it's there, after all, and Django couldn't care less _how_ you obtained your response.